# Generic extension method with an interface contraint

Tags: generics, interface, extension-methods

I have made a generic extension method (i.e AsXml) but still want a constraint with an interface (IXmlable) on some of my classes.

As soon as I have introduced my constraint, some of my methods are arguing with me.

One of my methods is returing a `List<Interest>` and the compiler says:

The type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MyWebApp.Entities.Extension.AsXml(T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'MyWebApp.Interfaces.IXmlable'.

This is my class:

```
public class Person : IXmlable
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Interest> Interests { get; set; } // My Interest class also implements IXmlable
}
```

My extension method looks like this:

```
 public static class Extension
    {
        public static string AsXml<T>(this T entity) where T : IXmlable
        {
             return MakeItXml(entity);
        }
    }
```

This my method:

```
return MyMethodThatReturnsAListOfPersons().AsXml();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like

```
return MyMethodThatReturnsAListOfPersons().Select(p => p.AsXml()).ToList();
```

assuming `MyMethodThatReturnsAListOfPersons` returns a `List<Person>` and you want to create a `List<string>` containing xml.

This is because `List<T>` does not implement your `IXmlable` interface, so you have to manually do the projection over each `Person` element in the list.

If you need to do this a lot you could create another extension method:

```
public static List<string> AsXmlList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq) where T : IXmlable
{
    return seq.Select(i => i.AsXml()).ToList();
}
```

so your code would then be:

```
return MyMethodThatReturnsAListOfPersons().AsXmlList();
```

Comment: or... he could add another extension method that operates on an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is `IXmlable`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen can you give an example. I would rather not introduce another level of linq mapping.

Comment: Ahh I see your updated post with the new extension method...let me try that. :)

Comment: How would my MyMethodThatReturnsAListOfPersons method be calling the new extension method?

Comment: @Lee yeah I did that ...but something is not working. It is because it is not a List<string> that I want to return but a single serialized string....let me try to do something.